# 504 Gateway Time-out in php curl_setopt

Tags: php, proxy

I am trying to hit the website url on the proxy url using a php code. I get it from google and trying to use it but when I run this code I am getting

> 504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time.

I am not able to find out real reason behind this error what I have to do for this .. Here is the code which I am using

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$timeout = 3000;
$proxies = file("proxy.txt");
$r="https://abcdefgh.com";
// Not more than 2 at a time
for($x=0;$x<25; $x++){
    //setting time limit to zero will ensure the script doesn't get timed out
    set_time_limit(0);

    //now we will separate proxy address from the port
    //$PROXY_URL=$proxies[$getrand[$x]];
    echo $proxies[$x];
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$r);
    curl_setopt($curl , CURLOPT_PROXY , $proxies[$x]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com/");
    $text = curl_exec($curl);

    echo "Hit Generated:";
    echo $x;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type of proxy. To me it looks you use HTTP proxy.

Comment: I am trying curl for first time.. can you please tell me how to define HTTP proxy?